# mouse disappears after locking and unlocking in XFCE + LightDM

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, mouse, lightdm, xfce

I have a fresh install of Xubuntu 16.04 on an ASRock Q1900-ITX (http://www.asrock.com/mb/intel/q1900-itx/). When I lock and unlock the mouse disappears. I tried installing GDM but that didn't fix anything.

I can't figure out how to fix this. Any ideas?

Here is my VGA details from `sudo lspci -vv`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 91
    Region 0: Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Region 2: Memory at c0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Region 4: I/O ports at f080 [size=8]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Address: fee0800c  Data: 41e1
    Capabilities: [b0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=07 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: I'd try locking by using xscreensaver instead. If not installed, it's in the repositories.

Comment: This is one of the known issues that had been noted in [Xubuntu 16.04 release announcement](http://xubuntu.org/news/xubuntu-16-04-release/). Workaround is noted there, but not a permanent solution.